# Gatsby develop command is producing an error

Tags: gatsby, contentful

I am trying to set up the "My Barcadia" template from Gatsby. So far I have followed the Readme which offers a well explained set up guide. All accounts and CLIs have been installed/created. This template also requires an API connection to Contentful. The account and the "Space" is set up and I have the necessary tokens available. Here is a part of the Readme guide. Steps 1,2 and 4 have been successfully completed. Step 3 produces the error below. The root from step 3 has been renamed to "patricklemmerdev".

````
1.  **Create a Gatsby site.**

    Use the Gatsby CLI to create a new site, specifying the Barcadia starter.

    ```shell
    # create a new Gatsby site using the barcadia starter
    gatsby new my-barcadia-starter https://github.com/bagseye/barcadia
    ```

2.  **Before running Gatsby Develop**

    You'll need to setup a free account with Contentful [Here](https://www.contentful.com/) and create a space ID and access token for your new site.

    Once these are generated create a new file in the site root called `.env.development` and populate it with the following information:

    ```
    CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID={YOUR SPACE ID}
    CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN={YOUR ACCESS TOKEN}
    ```

    **NOTE** - Ensure this file has been added to your `.gitignore` to prevent it from being tracked

3.  **Start developing.**

    Navigate into your new site’s directory and start it up.

    ```shell
    cd my-barcadia-starter/
    gatsby develop
    ```

4.  **Import Content-model.json on Contentful**
    Make a Json file(e.g. example-config.json) with the following content.

    ```
    {
      "spaceId": "SPACE_ID",
      "managementToken": "Generate a management token from the APIs Tab on contentful dashboard",
      "contentFile": "content-model.json"
     }
    ```

    Important Note: you need contentful globally installed(`npm i -g contentful-cli`) before the next step
    Then Run this Command from your terminal:
    `contentful space import --config example-config.json`

5.  **Open your site**

    Your site is now running at `http://localhost:8000`!

    _Note: You'll also see a second link: _`http://localhost:8000/___graphql`_. This is a tool you can use to experiment with querying your data. Learn more about using this tool in the [Gatsby tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-five/#introducing-graphiql)._

    Open the `my-barcadia-starter` directory in your code editor of choice and edit `src/pages/index.js`. Save your changes and the browser will update in real time!

6.  **Build your site**

    When you are ready to build your production site, you will need to create a `.env.production` file that will contain the `CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID` and `CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` environment variables. After that is set up, you can run `npm run build` or `gatsby build` and Gatsby will build your site.
````

In order to start developing the template I need to run "gatsby develop", which **should** start the localhost:8000. This is where I receive an error which I don't understand and so far fail to find answers for.(see the screenshot)

[image]

I have a) deleted and created a new space in Contentful and b) triple checked both spaceID, access token and management token.

Since the error is specifically saying its not able to access environment master, I created a development environment, which doesn't seem to have helped either.

I am using:

- Gatsby CLI 4.16.0
- Contentful CLI 1.14.9

and here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "barcadia",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A super-fast site using GatsbyJS",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^15.10.1",
    "@contentful/rich-text-types": "^15.10.1",
    "@fontsource/heebo": "^4.5.2",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^5.5.5",
    "gatsby": "^4.8.1",
    "gatsby-background-image": "^1.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.6.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^5.4.0",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^7.14.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.4.0",
    "gbimage-bridge": "^0.2.0",
    "gsap": "^3.9.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.7",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/bagseye/barcadia"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/bagseye/barcadia/issues"
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is the gatsby-config file:

```
/**
 * Configure your Gatsby site with this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/
 */
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "Patrick Lemmer",
    description: "Portfolio Website",
    author: "Morgan Baker",
    twitterUsername: "patricklemmer",
    githubUsername: "patricklemmer",
    instagramUsername: "patrick_lemmer",
    linkedinUsername: "patricklemmer",
    youtubeUsername: "patricklemmer",
    image: "/macbook-color.jpg",
    siteUrl: "https://patricklemmer.dev",
    developerName: "Patrick Lemmer",
    developerUrl: "https://patricklemmer.dev",
  },
  /* Your site config here */
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        // Learn about environment variables: https://gatsby.dev/env-vars
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt",
      options: {
        host: "https://barcadia.netlify.com",
        sitemap: "https://barcadia.netlify.com/sitemap.xml",
        policy: [{ userAgent: "*", allow: "/" }],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
  ],
}
```

**Question:** Does anyone have an idea on what to do or what to look for? Any help is appreciated. TIA

Comment: Can you share yout `gatsby-config.js`?

Comment: Sure, just did. @FerranBuireu

Comment: Is the environment file named `.env.development`?

Comment: Yes and it contains the SpaceID and Access Token for the Space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you've added a bracket (`{}`) in the environment variable?

It should look like:

```
CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID=123456
CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN=123456
```

According to the output error message it seems to contain a bracket.

If this doesn't solve the issue, try directly adding your `spaceId` and the access token directly in the configuration like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
  options: {
    spaceId: "123456" // process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    // Learn about environment variables: https://gatsby.dev/env-vars
    accessToken: "123456" // process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  },
},
```

Comment: Alright, that did the trick. I had indeed used { } in the file. After erasing them the develop compiled (with a another error), but since my original issue seems to be solved I will accept your answer and open another question for the new issue. Thanks!